# Optimize QUERY JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm working on a transport program that forces me to create a long query to search for possible routes. I need to optimize the query as much as possible. It calculates stopovers between bus stops. People get off at one stop and get on at another within a radius in kilometers. I have to ensure that the path is not prevented by some rules.

How can I optimize the query?

The problem is the relationship between t2 and t3 and the relationship between t5 and t6 which are joined by a radius.

```
SELECT '3' AS type, s1.id_sott AS id_sott1,s2.id_sott AS id_sott2,s3.id_sott AS id_sott3,s4.id_sott AS id_sott4, s5.id_sott AS id_sott5,s6.id_sott AS id_sott6, '0' AS id_sott7, '0' AS id_sott8, ch1.changeid as changeid1, ch2.changeid as changeid2, '0' AS changeid3,
    ABS((s2.distance - s1.distance)) as dist1, ABS((s4.distance - s3.distance)) as dist2, ABS((s6.distance - s5.distance)) as dist3,'0' AS dist4, (ABS((s2.distance - s1.distance)) + ABS((s4.distance - s3.distance)) + ABS((s6.distance - s5.distance)) ) AS km,
    s1.id_corsa AS id_corsa1,s3.id_corsa AS id_corsa2,s5.id_corsa AS id_corsa3,'0' AS id_corsa4, s1.orario AS orariostart1,s2.orario AS orariostop1, s3.orario AS orariostart2, s4.orario AS orariostop2,s5.orario AS orariostart3, s6.orario AS orariostop3,'0' AS orariostart4,
    IFNULL(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(corse)
        FROM regole_linee
        WHERE ('2023-02-24' BETWEEN da AND a )
        AND FIND_IN_SET( (DAYOFWEEK( '2023-02-24' ) -1 ) , giorni_sett)
        AND id_az= 28 AND stato=1
        , '0'
    ) AS rl,
    111.111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(t3.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t2.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t3.lon - t2.lon)) + SIN(RADIANS(t3.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(t2.lat))))) AS dist_frompart1,
    111.111 * DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(t5.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t4.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(t5.lon - t4.lon)) + SIN(RADIANS(t5.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(t4.lat))))) AS dist_frompart2,
    '0' AS dist_frompart3

FROM corse_fermate AS s1
INNER JOIN corse_fermate AS s2 ON s1.id_corsa = s2.id_corsa 
INNER JOIN corse_fermate AS s3
INNER JOIN corse_fermate AS s4 ON s3.id_corsa = s4.id_corsa 
INNER JOIN corse_fermate AS s5
INNER JOIN corse_fermate AS s6 ON s5.id_corsa = s6.id_corsa 
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t ON t.id_sott=s1.id_sott
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t2 ON t2.id_sott=s2.id_sott 
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t3 ON t3.id_sott=s3.id_sott
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t4 ON t4.id_sott=s4.id_sott 
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t5 ON t5.id_sott=s5.id_sott
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc AS t6 ON t6.id_sott=s6.id_sott 
/*
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc_tratte AS tt1 ON (s1.id_sott=tt1.id_sott1 AND s2.id_sott=tt1.id_sott2) 
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc_tratte AS tt2 ON (s3.id_sott=tt2.id_sott1 AND s4.id_sott=tt2.id_sott2)
INNER JOIN tratte_sottoc_tratte AS tt3 ON (s5.id_sott=tt3.id_sott1 AND s6.id_sott=tt3.id_sott2) 
*/

INNER JOIN changeover AS ch1 ON s2.id_sott=ch1.changeid
INNER JOIN changeover AS ch2 ON s4.id_sott=ch2.changeid 

WHERE s1.id_sott = 3
AND s6.id_sott = 85
AND s2.ordine > s1.ordine AND s4.ordine > s3.ordine AND s6.ordine > s5.ordine
AND s1.id_corsa != s3.id_corsa AND s1.id_corsa != s5.id_corsa AND s3.id_corsa != s5.id_corsa
AND s1.id_sott != s2.id_sott AND s6.id_sott != s4.id_sott AND s2.id_sott != s4.id_sott
AND s1.stato=1 AND s3.stato=1  AND s5.stato=1 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s2.orario, s3.orario) >= 0
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s2.orario, s3.orario) <= 180
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s4.orario, s5.orario) >= 0
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, s4.orario, s5.orario) <= 180 


/*AND s1.id_az=1 AND s2.id_az=1 AND s3.id_az=1 AND s4.id_az=1 AND s5.id_az=1 AND s6.id_az=1 AND ch1.id_az=1 AND ch2.id_az=1 */

GROUP BY s1.id_sott,s2.id_sott,s3.id_sott,s4.id_sott,s5.id_sott,s6.id_sott,s1.id_corsa,s3.id_corsa,s5.id_corsa 

HAVING dist_frompart1 < 5
AND dist_frompart2 < 5
AND find_in_set(s1.id_corsa,rl) = 0  
AND find_in_set(s3.id_corsa,rl) = 0 
AND find_in_set(s5.id_corsa,rl) = 0 

ORDER BY km ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Always add a tag for the dbms used. Especially when you're asking about performance. (The above query is not SQL standard compliant, and will raise an error on many DBSMS:s.)

Comment: Please would you add the EXPLAIN output to your question?

Comment: What do you mean, "The problem is ..."? What does that have to do with what you want to ask? What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question you are trying to ask? [mre] [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [ask] [Help] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: the result is great and I get what I want.
When I write 'The problem is' it means the time where the query takes up the most resources. it takes more resources to search for the combinations between t2 and t3 and between t4 and t5 because they are not united by id but by a radius of kilometers. the query also takes time if I increase the time 180(3 hours) because it evaluates other combinations

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please act on all the feedback. Please don't edit in a way that invalidates existing reasonable answers. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a subquery, you can do a left join with the `regole_linee` table, you will have the same result with less effort.

Comment: OP has been consistent in using table names/aliases when accessing columns but none in sub-query, so I assume (might be a mistake) it is non-correlated and will only be evaluated once.

Comment: Well, we need to know which table(s) `BETWEEN da AND a` references.

Comment: I inserted an image in the first post of the table: regole_linee

Answer (score 0):

These indexes *may* help performance:

```
corse_fermate:  INDEX(stato, id_sott, ordine, id_corsa, distance, orario)
tratte_sottoc:  INDEX(id_sott,  lat, long)
```

Does `regole_linee` have an index *starting with* `id_az`?

`DATE_FORMAT( '2023-02-24 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )` can be simplified to simply `'2023-02-24'`.

D

Comment: you are right it is useless to indicate the format of the date. I edited the post with the new query.
instead the regole_linee table (I inserted an image in the first post) is a rules table where the corse (s1.id_corsa, s3.icorsa, s4.id_corsa, etc.) to be excluded are entered. the structure is simple:
corsa,da(date from),a(date to),stato(status rules),id_az(if the rule belongs to that company. every (id_az)company making the query with own rules).